# can we loop similar events in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

being specific .. the code

```
$("#ht_1").click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});

$("#ht_2").click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});

// what i tried
for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    $("#ht_" + i).click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
}
```

What's wrong in this code, any alternatives for doing this??

edited:sorry

Comment: what is `ht_1`? if it's ID you need to use `#`

Comment: Assuming you have elements with those ids, your code should work. Is it in a `$(document).ready()` callback?

Comment: oops a silly mistake and i asked stackoverflow .. what a moron .. sorry ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selector like as follows for elements which id starts with `ht`

```
$("[id^='ht_']").click(function(){
});
```

Comment: Do you have to put a `#` before that regular expression?

Answer (score 4):

Your code intends that `ht_1, ht_2` is a tags but it seems id, you can use [attribute selector , starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/pxX5z/)**

**Syntax:** `jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )`

```
$('*[id^="ht_"]').click(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

You can find different useful selector like contains, ends with, stats with, equal etc on this jQuery api [**link**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks @Blender, used mistakenly.

Comment: hmm... `*` isn't really necessary, is it?

Comment: * is used for contains, but here I thinks starts with would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a class to all elements you want a click function on.

Example:

```
/** CSS fragment **/
$(".htClass").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
});


<!-- html fragment -->
<div class="htClass">content 1</div>
<div class="htClass anotherClass">content 2</div>
<!-- here, another class is additionally assigned -->
```

Simply assign `htClass` to any element you want that specific function to be executed for.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not selectors... Most likely you either need $(".ht_"+i) or $("#ht_"+i)... Apart from that, it should work IMO.

Answer (score 0):

What is `ht_1`? For classes, you need to use `.ht_1`, for IDs it should be `#ht_1`. And if you have lots of similar elements, [`$.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) may be a good choice.

Comment: `.live()` was replaced with the event delegation syntax of `.on()` a while ago.